# How to write an error struct which can contain different strongly typed enums as the error code?

Tags: c++, error-handling, enums, c++17

I want to write an simple error struct which contains an error code of some kind and a `std::string` as the message. The error code could be a simple int, or any kind of strongly typed enum e.g.:

```
enum class NetworkErrorCode {
OK = 0,
CONNECTION_FAILURE,
EMPTY_RESPONSE,
HOST_RESOLUTION_FAILURE,
UNKNOWN_ERROR = 1000,
};
```

I could write a struct which has different overloaded constructors for each different enum it could contain which all convert them into `int` to store them. But in this case I would loose the possibility to compare the error code against the actual enum values later on. I would also need to write a comparison operator for each of the possible types.

I could also use templates like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct Error
{
  T const code;
  std::string const message;
};
```

But now I would not be able to create an Error like this:

`Error{NetworkErrorCode::CONNECTION_FAILURE, "some message"}`.

I would need to write:

`Error<NetworkErrorCode>{NetworkErrorCode::CONNECTION_FAILURE, "some message"}`.

Is there a way to avoid writing a lot of boiler plate code like in the first solution while still maintaining the possibility to create them without explicitly specifying the typename? I have heard about template argument deduction for class template constructors in c++17 but I cant get my head around it.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to add a ctor, as the following

```
Error(T const t, const string s)  : code(t), message(s) {}
```

Then by using a c++17 compliant compiler you will be all set.

You can check it on Godbolt, https://godbolt.org/g/Dyznp8

Note that this uses C++17 template argument deduction for class template constructors instead of using variant.

The full sample code is listed here for your reference,

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

enum class NetworkErrorCode {
    OK = 0,
    CONNECTION_FAILURE,
    EMPTY_RESPONSE,
    HOST_RESOLUTION_FAILURE,
    UNKNOWN_ERROR = 1000
};

template<typename T>
struct Error
{
  T const code;
  std::string const message;
  Error(T const t, const string s)  : code(t), message(s) {}
};

template <typename T>
auto getStuff() -> variant<string, Error<T>> {
    variant<string, Error<T>> w;
    return w;
}

int main() {
    int i = 2;
    if (i == 1) {
        Error{NetworkErrorCode::CONNECTION_FAILURE, "some message"};
    }
}
```

You can compile it with `-std=c++17`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it almost works completely the way I want. The only thing left is that I currently still need to specify the concrete type if I want to return it from a function. `auto getStuff() -> std::variant<std::string, Error<int>>;` is there also a way around this?

Comment: Check my updated answer. If this is what you want please vote and/or accept this as the answer so otherwise will know.

Comment: How would I call it? `auto result = getStuff()` gives me `No matching function for cal`

Comment: you will have to specify `getStuff<int>` because you don't have a parameter for getStuff(). if  you can have something like , getStuff(T input), then the compiler will deduce the type for you.

Comment: It actually has a string as a parameter, I removed it to simplify it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

```
using error_code = std::variant<int, NetworkErrorCode, AnotherErrorCode /*etc*/>;

struct Error {
  error_code code;
  std::string message;
};
```

this requires you to list all of the error code types in one spot; but this is less work than writing the constructors you want to write.

```
Error{NetworkErrorCode::CONNECTION_FAILURE, "some message"}
```

works without writing additional constructors because variant will convert from any of its possible types.

To get access you have `std::visit` or `.get<Type>()` or the like.  `==` on `error_code` should usually just work (sometimes you may have to cast the other argument to `error_code` explicitly).